# How do I add a custom view to iPhone app's UI?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

I'm diving into iPad development and I'm still learning how everything works together.  I understand how to add standard view (i.e. buttons, tableviews, datepicker, etc.) to my UI using both Xcode and Interface Builder, but now I'm trying to add a custom calendar control (TapkuLibrary) to the left window in my UISplitView application which doesn't involve Interface Builder, right?  So if I have a custom view (in this case, the TKCalendarMonthView), how do I programmatically add it to one of the views in my UI (in this case, the RootViewController)?  Below are some relevant code snippets from my project...

**RootViewController interface**

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> {

    DetailViewController *detailViewController;

    NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet DetailViewController *detailViewController;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender;
```

**TKCalendarMonthView interface**

```
@class TKMonthGridView,TKCalendarDayView;
@protocol TKCalendarMonthViewDelegate, TKCalendarMonthViewDataSource;


@interface TKCalendarMonthView : UIView {

    id <TKCalendarMonthViewDelegate> delegate;
    id <TKCalendarMonthViewDataSource> dataSource;

    NSDate *currentMonth;
    NSDate *selectedMonth;
    NSMutableArray *deck;


    UIButton *left;
    NSString *monthYear;
    UIButton *right;

    UIImageView *shadow;
    UIScrollView *scrollView;


}
@property (readonly,nonatomic) NSString *monthYear;
@property (readonly,nonatomic) NSDate *monthDate;
@property (assign,nonatomic) id <TKCalendarMonthViewDataSource> dataSource;
@property (assign,nonatomic) id <TKCalendarMonthViewDelegate> delegate;

- (id) init;
- (void) reload;
- (void) selectDate:(NSDate *)date;
```

Thanks in advance for all your help!  I still have a ton to learn, so I apologize if the question is absurd in any way.  I'm going to continue researching this question right now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have initialized the custom `UIView`, you need to add it as a subview of the `viewController`'s view.

[- (void)addSubview:(UIView *)view](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/addSubview:)

So an example would be if you have a plain `viewController` called `myVC`, which has simply a blank white `UIView` as its view, you would say this:

```
CGRect customViewsFrame = CGRectMake(10, 30, 5, 2);
MyCustomView *myView = [[MyCustomView alloc] initWithFrame:customViewsFrame];
[[myVC view] addSubview:myView];
[myView release]; //Since you called "alloc" on this, you have to release it too
```

Then it will show up in the `viewController`'s view, taking up the space indicated by the `CGRect`.

The `CGRect`'s coordinates specify a location **in the local coordinate system of the superview you are adding to**, if I'm not mistaken.

[CGRect CGRectMake (CGFloat x, CGFloat y, CGFloat width, CGFloat height);](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectMake)

Comment: Thanks, Chris!  That makes sense.  How do I position it in the parent view?  Is that something I do during the initialization of the custom view?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not booted into Mac OS X so I can't verify this completely, but this is your general pattern:

RootViewController.h:

```
...
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>
{
    ...
    TKCalendarMonthView* calendarView;
    ...
}
...
@property (nonatomic, retain) TKCalendarMonthView* calendarView;
...
```

RootViewController.m:

```
...
@synthesize calendarView;
...
- (void)dealloc
{
    ...
    [calendarView release];
    ...
}
...
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...
    TKCalendarMonthView* aCalendarView = [[TKCalendarMonthView alloc] init]; // <-- possibly initWithFrame here
    self.calendarView = aCalendarView;
    [aCalendarView release];
    [self addSubview:self.calendarView];
    ...
}
```