# add custom switch to iphone view

Tags: iphone, user-interface, custom-controls

I am using the following code to create a custom switch:

```
UISegmentedControl* switchView=[[UISegmentedControl alloc] 
                                initWithItems:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"On",@"Off",nil]];
[switchView setFrame:CGRectMake(20,365,140,28)];
switchView.selectedSegmentIndex=0;
switchView.segmentedControlStyle=UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
[switchView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"onSelected.png"] forSegmentAtIndex:0];
[switchView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"off.png"] forSegmentAtIndex:1];
[switchView addTarget:self action:@selector(checkOnOffState:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

I would now like to add this control to one of my screens (I believe the correct term is ViewController?). How would I do this in Xcode 4.3?

I looked at a few other posts and was not able to find anything that works. For example, [How do I add a custom view to iPhone app's UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823488/how-do-i-add-a-custom-view-to-iphone-apps-ui) suggested something along the lines of 
`[[myVC view] addSubview:myView];` 
and [How to customize UISwitch button in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087546/how-to-customize-uiswitch-button-in-iphone) suggested 
`self.navigationItem.titleView=switchView;`
If possible, could you also explain why these approaches did not work? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a class for your switch which is subclass of your UISegmentControl , 
Else you can add this code in your vc directly as well.

Add this code in its initWithFrame method

and then use it in your VC

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
  urCustomSwitch  = [urCustomSwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,365,140,28)];
  [self.view addSubview:urCustomSwitch];
}
```

This shall serve your purpose if you are to create custom reusable class.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Should I make this class a subclass of UITableViewController, UITableViewCell, AppDelegate, CIColor, or CIContext. I would have though that I should make this a subclass of UIView, but that is not one of the options. Thanks again.

Comment: U can make it a subclass of `UISegmentControl` or `UIView` is also an option

Comment: This is not working for me because my custom switch does not have an alloc method. Is there something that I have to do to be able to use it or do I have to instantiate it in another way?

Comment: If you subclass any UIControl or UIView, you need to override this method and in which you will write your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you add this switch control  i.e. `UISegmentedControl` in `InterfaceBuilder` (.xib file)

This task will be much easier for you.

Comment: do you mean adding my custom class that is a subclass of UISegmentedControl to the InterfaceBuilder. Can I do this just by creating the .xib file? Thanks.